# Redirect to HTTP from HTTPS on mobile broswer not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, https

So I have this page on my site where its the only page thats not secure which is what I want. Question is on a desktop browser, my htaccess file redirects the user when the user clicks on the link to the HTTP page

```
<li class="<?php if($pagename == 'music_search.php'){echo 'active active';}?>"><a href="music_search.php" target="_self" class="">Music Search</a></li>
```

This works fine on the desktop browser. But when I check it out on a mobile browser I click on the link and it takes me to the HTTPS version of the page. I need to have HTTP for desktop browser and mobile browser just for this page. I have cleared the cache on the phone browser and added meta tags to prevent caching but its still not redirecting to HTTP

Here is my htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/music_search.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```

Any help would be nice. I been at this for hours now. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Out of interest, why must the page be HTTP?

Comment: There is an API call that use only HTTP so I cant have HTTP in HTTPS

Answer (score 0):

Not an .htaccess file solution but I did quick hack using php. Here is a php solution

```
<?php
$file = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];
$break = Explode('/', $file);
$page = $break[count($break) - 1];
$page = substr($page, 0 , -4);

if($page == 'music_search' && isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])){
header('Location: http://www.example.com/music_search.php');

}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

I know I have to do this for other files which will not require http but when the time comes I will fix it again.